# Plotting dataframe columns using a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have the following data in a dataframe. I wrote a for loop so every column would be plotted against BOND, ANGEL and DIHED.

[image: My DataFrame]

I run this code

```
col=["TS","BOND","ANGEL","DIHED"]
df1=DataFrame(Energy, column=col)
df1=df1.astype(float)

for i in col:
    print(x)
    df1.plot(x="i", y="TS",)
    plt.show()
```

but i get KeyError: 'i'.

How can i manage to run a loop over my DataFrame so at the end i can have 4 plots each TS on Y-Axis and other 3 columns separately on x-Axis?

bdw i can plot the TS only but if I add the x axis it causes problem.

Comment: You're passing in the string literal "i", your loop should use the variable `i` (no quotes)

Comment: yes thats true, but this was one of the 100 variatuins i tries to get any result. I just tries with df1.plot(y="TS",x=i). still nothing but KeyError: 'TS'.

Comment: What if you only pass, not in a loop, `df1.plot()`? What does it show, and what are the entries in the legend?

Comment: it spits out all the data at once. x axis goes from 0 to 9 and y axis is variable. Bdw i found the answer finally by myself. Thanks for taking part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a code which will work perfectly now.

```
for i in col[1:]:
    print(i)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(df1["TS"],df1[i])
    plt.show()
```

with this code it will be possible to loop over a DataFrame and return for every column a separate plot. df1["TS"] will be in this case the x axis and is fixed and df1[i] is the y axis which will be variable.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. As in my answer (which is the same as what you already found) the problem is that you cannot plot a column against itself, which is an open bug report with the Pandas dev team. Really though, for your purpose, `x='TS, y='TS'` would just be a straight line anyway.

Answer (score 3):

After researching, it looks like this is an open bug. You [cannot plot a column against itself](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22088)

If I make a DF as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"TS":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                 "BOND":[54,34,54,56,34,12,34,56,78],
                 "ANGEL":[34,56,47,14,58,70,36,14,36],
                 "DIHED":[13,46,57,37,15,48,59,26,15]})
df
    TS BOND ANGEL DIHED
0   1   54  34  13
1   2   34  56  46
2   3   54  47  57
3   4   56  14  37
4   5   34  58  15
5   6   12  70  48
6   7   34  36  59
7   8   56  14  26
8   9   78  36  15
```

and I put it into a loop as such:

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df.plot(x=col, y='TS')
```

I get 3 plots, one with each other column plotted against 'TS'